# Max value grouped by two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is to select the maximum value from a tabel and group by two fields. The table is very large, say 5billion records and the data is arranged like this:

```
LocationNumber | Event | Value
             1 |     1 |    10
             1 |     2 |    20
             1 |     3 |    30
             2 |     1 |    20
             2 |     2 |    50
```

I'd like to have the output as

```
LocationNumber | Event | Value
             1 |     3 |    30
             2 |     2 |    50
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by two fields? Your output doesn't show that!

Comment: To arrive at the desired result you have few choices regardless of the number of records - BUT, you should be certain that you choose the method you actually need. Do you want max(event) and max(value) - OR - do you want the value that corresponds to the highest event number per locationNumber. These are not the exactly the same things. Regarding performance, that will depend on many factors including your indexes and freshnes of statistics.

Answer (score 4):

Just `GROUP BY LocationNumber` and use `MAX` like this:

```
SELECT LocationNumber, MAX(Event), Max(value)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY LocationNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
    LocationNumber,
    Event,
    Value
from(
    select
        LocationNumber,
        Event,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by LocationNumber order by Event desc, Value desc) RNum
    From YourTable
)x where RNum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT LocationNumber, MAX(Event), Max(value)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY LocationNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

select LocationNumber, MAX(event), MAX(Val) from #tbl
group by LocationNumber

this will work, But I am concerned about 5 billion records. Will it perform effectively ?